# How to preprocess scoped css (sass)

Tags: riot.js

Does anyone know how to do this? Riot scoped css would be awesome if only I could use SASS. I checked the [docs](http://riotjs.com/api/compiler/) but couldn't understand what's required.

I would like to be able to:

```
<style scoped>
  @extend %my-sass-extension;

  h1 {
    color: $my-color;
  }
</style
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import scss in script tag， if you use webpack, like this:

```
<script>
  import './page-head.scss'
</script>
```

And my webpack config:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
...
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
        }]
    }]
}
};
```